# Colocando Javascript dentro Div

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Possuo esse codigo para mostrar a data esse

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
now = new Date
document.write ("Esquenta Black Friday Somente Hoje  " + now.getDate() + " do " + now.getMonth() + 1, )
// ]]></script>
```

Precisava por ele dentro de uma div para utilizar essas configurações de CSS

```
.promocoes-kit {

background: #fff1dc;

 width: 80%;

 height: 50%;

  margin: auto;

 border-radius: 10px;

border: solid 4px white;

box-shadow: 3px 3px #bdbcbc5e;
}

.promocoes-kit{

 font-size: initial;

text-align: center;

 font-weight: 600;

 color: #ea9b2a;

  width: fit-content;

 padding: 10px 30px;
}

.promocoes-label{

 padding: 0;

  margin: 0;

 text-align: center;

 font-size: large;

 color: #ea9b2a;

 font-weight: 600;
}
```

Alguém sabe dizer como faço isso? Vou utilizar ele numa LADING PAGE como banner no Magento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que percebi você não tem muito conhecimento com **Javascript**, então segue algumas considerações:

> **1-** Você está usando **document.write** o que é pouco indicado pois ele sobrescreve todo seu **HTML**.
>
> **2-** Sempre o mais indicado é você declarar variáveis com a palavra chave **var** ou **let**, por **N** motivos.
>
> **3-** Quando você faz isto `now.getMonth() + 1`, você terá o mês anterior mais um ou seja **101** sendo que o certo seria colocar dentro de parenteses para formar uma expressão assim `(now.getMonth() + 1)`.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('teste');
var datas = new Date();

div.innerHTML = 'Esquenta Black Friday Somente Hoje  ' + datas.getDate() + ' do ' + (datas.getMonth() +1);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

#teste {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="teste"></div>
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado pela explicação, perfeito.